# executable jar using ant and ivy - CLASSPATH issues

Tags: ant, ivy, manifest.mf

I'm trying to build an executable jar file using ant managed by ivy but am stuck. Our original build-script assembles the jar file more or less okay. The dependencies are in the manifest.mf but not under Class-Path but rather Compile-Class-Path entry.

I can simply set the Main-Class entry in the menifest file but having an impossible foe in trying to get the ivy dependencies in the Class-Path. While this seems simple enough using gradle I can't find any solution for ivy dependencies.

Is there a way of getting the resolves ivy dependencies and put them in the manifest? These dependencies are just paths to a network location where the jar files are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving a standard way to do this. If you can provide your actual build file, I can be more specific in the answer.

You can do this in the ant target for jar creation. For ex:

```
<!-- create a classpath variable with all the jars needed for runtime -->
<path id="cls.path">
   <!-- declare all the paths that you need. For ex: all resolved jars in "runtime" conf --> 
</path>
<!-- If your path has folder prefix, you'll have to do <pathconvert> -->
<jar jarfile="${jar_name}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
   <manifest>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${cls.path}"/>
      ...
      <!-- You can add standard jar properties and any custom property here -->
   </manifest>
</jar>
```

Comment: Yeah well that much I know but the part that interests me is: <!-- declare all the paths that you need. For ex: all resolved jars in "runtime" conf -->
How can I do that automatically? We have a couple hundred transitive dependencies resolved by ivy, I'm not intending to type them all in.

Comment: You don't have to declare each jar. You can create path variable in multiple ways. One way is to use the ivy cache. This can be done by declaring something like `<ivy:cachepath pathid="default.classpath" conf="runtime" />`. This will create a path with all jars resolved under "runtime" conf. Another way is to create a path with <fileset> child with `<include name="**/*.jar">`

Comment: @smoothed9 how would one re-use cachepath variable on the next build without having to run the SLOW `cachepath` task again?